# html2pdf error when it's present the <ul> tag

Tags: php, html2pdf

When my HTML code contains a long text in a `<ul><li>my long text...</li></ul>` tags, at the end of the line, after the PDF generation, the text does not go in a new line, but it's placed after the PDF right margin.

Because it, the structure of my PDF is incorrect.

Thanks for your precious help !

Answer (score 1):

I've used some of these HTML -> PDF tools and you have to remember something: none of them is perfect. Something will work wrong, or different as you wanted to in them. The one I've been able to build more complex HTML structures (and make them work in PDF) is [mPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php), give it a try if you want!

Aside from that, your question isn't basically a question, you aren't giving any code example, or anything, we can't know for sure if the problem is html2pdf or your code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Using mPDF my problem disappeared.